# detect event on drag column from tool panel in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

I need event on dragging column from tool panel , 
is any way to detect drag and move column from tool panel ?
thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Regarding ag-grid documentation found here https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/

```
var gridOptions = {
   ...
   onDragStarted: function() {alert('Start move...')},
   onDragStopped: function() {alert('End move...')},
   ...
};
```

Please note that both actions will be launched also on drag n drop event from global Columns header - I do not know if this will be an issue for you.